# show create procedure procedure_name into a variable in MySql

Tags: mysql

Here We want to Create a script to copy the store procedure from one DB to Another DB in MYSQL,

```
show create procedure procedure_name
```

This command show the store procedure definition of Store Procedure.
How to store the output of the above command in temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Threat it like a select statement and fetch the result (which is one row and one column).

Fetching the result to the script and pushing it back is probably the easiest way. If you don't like that approach a server side cursor could do it.

Comment: please share the query

Comment: `show create procedure procedure_name` is the query

Comment: How to use this query in select statement

Comment: There is no select statement. Use the query, *pretending* it is a select statement.

Comment: How can we store the output of this statement in temp table